# Fabric connection to EC2 instance fails with Paramiko ValueError

Tags: amazon-ec2, fabric, paramiko

I'm trying to connect to an EC2 instance using fabric (in python).  I've set my env variables as so:

```
env.hosts = ['xxx-xxx.amazonaws.com']
env.user = "ubuntu"
env.key_filename = ['/path/to/my/ec2.pem']
```

the command

```
run('pwd')
```

gives the following error:

```
File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/paramiko/client.py", line 242, in connect
File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/paramiko/transport.py", line 346, in start_client
ValueError: CTR mode needs counter parameter, not IV
```

I'm using paramiko 1.14.0 (current) btw, and editing my ssh config to associate the pem to the host is not an option (although, I have tested the connection with ssh -i /path/to/pem and that was fine).  Has anyone else had this problem and solved it?

Answer (score 3):

I had the same error running a Python/Paramiko script on a new Ubunutu host.  I wasn't able to determine the cause of the fault as I am new to Python but I resolved it by removing paramiko and its dependancies from `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages`.  I removed paramiko, pycrypto and ecdsa.

My system already has the following packages:

```
sudo apt-get install python-pip
sudo apt-get install python-dev
```

I re-installed paramiko with:

```
sudo pip install paramiko
```

I was able to run my script successfully without the the ValueError:

Versions of modules I am running:

```
ecdsa 0.11
paramiko 1.14.0
pycrypto 2.6.1
```

Comment: thanks!  do you happen to know which versions of paramiko, pycrypto, and ecdsa you're running now?  that might help me a lot in debugging this error...

Comment: Edited my post to include the version info.